# How can I access rehydrated redux-persist state from a react-router-dom loader?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, redux-persist

I'm trying to get rehydrated redux-persist state in a react-router-dom loader, but am only getting initial state.

My index.tsx:

```
import store, { persistor } from "./store/store";
...
import Profile, { loader as profileLoader } from './components/Profile/Profile';
...
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <App />, // This should be the root route
        errorElement: <Error />,
        children: [
            ....
            {
                path: '/profile',
                element: <Profile />,
                loader: profileLoader
            }
        ],
    },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                <RouterProvider router={router} />
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

My store.tsx:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { userReducer } from "./slices/userSlice";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    debug: true
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export default store;
```

My Profile.tsx:

```
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom';
import store from '../../store/store';

export async function loader() {
    console.log(`loader: ${JSON.stringify(store.getState().user)}`);
    return store.getState().user;
    // GLOBAL STATE DOESN'T REHYDRATE TIL AFTER LOADERS RUN
    // DON'T ACCESS GLOBAL STATE IN THE LOADER
}

export default function Profile() {
    const globalState = store.getState().user;
    console.log(`component: ${JSON.stringify(globalState)}`);

    return (
        <h1>{globalState.username}</h1>
    );
}
```

By the time react-router-dom loads the data for the Profile route, I'm expecting Redux to be rehydrated. But here's what it actually is at that point in time, compared to accessing the same state in the functional component itself:

[image]

Based on the order of those logs, it seems like Redux rehydrates only *after* the loader runs. **Is there any way to rehydrate Redux *before* the route loader runs?** I am wrapping the router in a PersistGate, but that doesn't seem to be making the route loader wait for rehydration...

Comment: *Supposedly* the `PersistGate` is supposed to prevent rendering its children until the state is rehydrated, but you may need to wait for the hydration to complete and update a local state in some root component that conditionally renders the router.